# VS2019 - The key combination (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C) is bound to command (Comment Selection) which is not currently available

Tags: visual-studio-2019, keyboard-shortcuts

When highlighting a line and using the key combination 'Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C' to comment out code, I get the message:

> The key combination (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C) is bound to command (Comment
> Selection) which is not currently available

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

I have tried: 'Tools | Options | Keyboard | Reset' but this has not resolved the issue.

I'm editing an HTML file and haven't got any plugins installed in Visual Studio.

Comment: Seems to have been [reported and fixed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ctrlkc-does-not-work/926745). Try updating your VS?

Comment: Thanks, but I already have the latest version of VS.